# By latitude and longitude I can get address in emulator but not in android device

Tags: android

By giving latitude and longitude value I can get location in emulator but when I try same code in android device its not shown location though GPS is on.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the below link using asynctask to get the exact address..

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=lat,lng&sensor=false

Hope you will get the address string in result like below:

```
JSONArray mArray= jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
JSONObject jb = result.getJSONObject(0);
if (jb.has("formatted_address")) {
    addressText = jb.getString("formatted_address");
}
```

Comment: kindly up the answer.. it will be helpful for others and for my career